# How to trigger automated build in TFS 2017 only when an artifact is changed?

Tags: team-foundation-server, build-server, automated

I have installed TFS 2017. I want to setup the TFS in such a way that whenever any developer checks in code, an automated build is triggered for that solution only.
My application contains many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit your build configuration, go to the `Triggers` tab and enable `Continuous Integration`. There you can define path filters and specify the path to your solution folder, so the build will only be triggered when changes are checked in to that distinct path.